# How do I add multiple attachments to Powershell email script

Tags: shell, powershell

I am running a script to listen for new files in a specific folder. When it finds a new file I want email that file, and another file that I'm explicitly defining. here's a bit of code :

```
    $Report = "C:\somefolder\somefile.xml"
    $AnotherReport = "C:\somefolder\someotherfile.xml"
```

And a bit later I want to do something like this

```
    Send-MailMessage -Attachments $Report,$AnotherReport
```

I want to add more than one attachment from different locations. What is the proper syntax to do that?

Comment: Have you tested it? From my experience usually when you're inputting multiple things to a single parameter, attachments in this case, they are separated by a comma so in my mind this looks like it may work.

Comment: The help for `Send-MailMessage` says the `-Attachments` parameter accepts an array. (Why not test before you ask?)

Comment: Why do you think adding three attachments would be different from adding two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tested but you can try like this

```
#Converts to array
$Report = @("C:\somefolder\somefile.xml")
$AnotherReport = "C:\somefolder\someotherfile.xml"
$Report += $AnotherReport

Send-MailMessage -Attachments $Report
```