# Powershell foreach creates multiple csv files that I would like to have emailed once created. How may this be accomplished?

Tags: powershell, email, foreach, attachment

Powershell foreach creates multiple csv files that I would like to have emailed once created.
How may this be accomplished?
Can I create another foreach to send each of the newly named csv files or do I try and zip the output to be emailed?

```
#create a connection to the Exchange 2010 server  
.'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -Auto -AllowClobber

#this locates any mailbox that is equal or over 28GB and gets the user to create an individual csv file for that person The amount of created csv files may change at any time.

$mstat= Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics |
    ?{$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGB() -ge 28} |
    ForEach-Object {$_.DisplayName}

foreach ($user in $mstat){
#This creates the initial csv file with added columns to be added in later
Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $user |
    Select DisplayName,
    @{N='Storage Limit Status'; E={$_.StorageLimitStatus}}, 
    @{N="Total Items"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.ItemCount)}},
    @{N="Total Size in MB"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB())}}, 
    @{N="Total Size in GB"; E={"{0:N1}" -f($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGB())}}, 
    Database,'Folder Name',"Items in Folder",”Folder Size in MB” |
    Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | 
    Export-Csv C:\path\$user.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

#This adds the Folder sizes and appends the data to the already created csv file
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user |
    ? {$_.ItemsInFolder -gt 0} |
    Sort ItemsInFolder -Descending |
    Select @{N='Folder Name'; E={$_.Name}},
    @{N="Items in Folder"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.ItemsInFolder)}},
    @{N=”Folder Size in MB”;E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.FolderSize.ToMb())}} |      
    Export-Csv C:\path\$user.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -force

}

#Email is sent with the following

$From = "Exchange_Mailbox_Limit@email.com"
$To = "address@email.com”
$Attachment = "Path to csv(s) files"
$Subject = "Mailbox Size Getting Close to Limits"
$SMTPServer = "Server IP address"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment;
```

Comment: For me, better way would be zipping the csv files and send the zip once.
That way - you are making one request with Send-MailMessage and there is no mess in attachments :)

Comment: There are a few other answers here regarding [multiple attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477197/9164015) as [`Send-MailMesage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Send-MailMessage?view=powershell-5.1) takes an array for `-Attachments`. If you are on version 5.1 or above you can use [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) to "zip" files.

Comment: WRT the question, either approach can be taken. What would work best for the recipients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send all files separately with a variable
$files = (ls C:\path\mail).FullName

```
.'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1' Connect-ExchangeServer -Auto -AllowClobber


$mbox  = (Get-Mailbox).Alias | sort $_.Alias
$mstat = $mbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | ?{$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGB() -ge 26} |
            ForEach-Object {$_.DisplayName}
            

foreach ($user in $mstat){

Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $user |
    Select DisplayName,
    @{N='Storage Limit Status'; E={$_.StorageLimitStatus}}, 
    @{N="Total Items"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.ItemCount)}},
    @{N="Total Size in MB"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB())}}, 
    @{N="Total Size in GB"; E={"{0:N1}" -f($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGB())}}, 
    @{N="Warning Quota Limit (MB)"; E= {"{0:N0}" -f(30720 -($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()))}},
    @{N="Prohibit Mail Quota Limit (MB)"; E= {"{0:N0}" -f(40960 -($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()))}},
    'Folder Name',"Items in Folder",”Folder Size in MB” |
    Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | 
    Export-Csv C:\path\Mail\$user.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user |
    ? {$_.ItemsInFolder -gt 0} |
    Sort ItemsInFolder -Descending |
    Select @{N='Folder Name'; E={$_.Name}},
    @{N="Items in Folder"; E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.ItemsInFolder)}},
    @{N=”Folder Size in MB”;E={"{0:N0}" -f($_.FolderSize.ToMb())}} |      
    Export-Csv C:\path\Mail\$user.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -force

}

Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession *
$files = (ls C:\path\Mail).FullName



$From = "Mailbox_Limit@email.com"
$To = "email@email.com”
$Attachment = $files
$Subject = "Mailbox Size Getting Close to Limits"
$Body = "<h2>$mstat</h2><br><br>"
$SMTPServer = "x.x.x.x"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body ($mstat | Out-String) -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment;

Remove-Item C:\path\Mail\*
```